# Send Stripe token to java server

Tags: java, php, html, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get Stripe to send off the token my page gets to a java service running in the background, which will do all the handling. I don't do much web work, so I'm sorry if the answer is really obvious but I haven't been able to find anything online that tells me plain and simple how to get the token and send it.

Here's the code for my form

```
<form action="localhost:8080/api/charge" method="POST" id="monthButton">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_KEY"
    data-allow-remember-me="true"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-description="1 month"
    data-label="Purchase 1 month"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-name="Demo"
    data-zip-code="true">
  </script>
</form>
```

which is just sitting in the body of my HTML page. There isn't much to the server yet, and I'm open to changing how it works, but this is what I have for listening right now

```
private static HttpServer startServer() {
    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.asc");
    resourceConfig.register("javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter");
    resourceConfig.register("com.asc.CrossDomainFilter");

    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), resourceConfig);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final HttpServer server = startServer();
    System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at %s/application.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));

    final int in = System.in.read();

    System.out.print(String.format("In: %d", in));

    server.shutdown();
}
```

And this bit is basically just copied from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/charges).

```
@Path("/api")
public class StripeResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/charge")
    public void charge(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.print("Started");
        // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
        // See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
        Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_KEY";

        // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
        String token = request.getParameter("stripeToken");

        // Create a Customer
        Map<String, Object> customerParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        customerParams.put("source", token);
        customerParams.put("description", "Example customer");

        try {
            Customer customer = Customer.create(customerParams);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (APIConnectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CardException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (APIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
        try {
            Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chargeParams.put("amount", 1000); // amount in cents, again
            chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
            chargeParams.put("source", token);
            chargeParams.put("description", "Example charge");
            Map<String, String> initialMetadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
            initialMetadata.put("order_id", "6735");
            chargeParams.put("metadata", initialMetadata);

            Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
        } catch (CardException e) {
            // The card has been declined

    } catch (APIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (APIConnectionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ooc; The HTML page *isn't* hosted by the Java Server?  It's hosted by something else?  If it's hosted on the same server, try making the path relative (ie. change `action="localhost:8080/api/charge"` to `action="/api/charge"`)  If it's not, you'll probably run into some security issues, but you could try making it explicit (ie. change it to `action="http://localhost:8080/api/charge"`).

Is there a reason you're hosting this on two separate systems (if you even are)?

Comment: @andrewnelder Like I said, I'm not a web guy, but it needs to present and receive the info from the customer as a website. I wanted to be able to do whatever needs done in the page, then do all the rest in java since that's what I normally work with. Right now I'm not sure about pretty much anything in here, so there's a very high chance that there's bad code there.